# Multi tenant Rabbit MQ application using spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, multi-tenant

I am in need of implementing a multi tenant MQ (Rabbit MQ) application using spring boot and  spring integration. Having seen the javadocs, I assume AbstractRoutingConnectionFactory would suffice my requirement. But I am curious to know the usage of thread-bound context to determine the lookup for the target.

javadoc of AbstractRoutingConnectionFactory

> Abstract {@link ConnectionFactory} implementation that routes {@link #createConnection()}
>   calls to one of various target ConnectionFactories based on a lookup key. The latter is usually
>   (but not necessarily) determined through some thread-bound context.

I am trying to understand more on the abstractRouting that spring offers. Below is what I am trying to understand

1. Wouldn't a hashmap suffice the purpose of the lookup. I am trying to
   understand what advantage does the thread bound context brings in
   abstract routing ?
2. What advantages does the AbstractRoutingConnectionFactory brings in
       specific, since the same could be achieved using a simple if-else
       logic to determine the target from the hashmap?